# Insert Many to Many in EF With Some Logic

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, insert, many-to-many

I have many to many relationship in entity framework. See image...
[image: many to many]
I want to insert an article and tags for this article, **but** TagName property is unique in db and so I need only new tags to be inserted in `Tags` and in `ArticlesToTags`(not seen in EF) tables while others that are already in `Tags` need to be inserted only in `ArticlesToTags`.

```c#
public void CreateUpdate(string title, string subTitle, string text,
                string author, string tags, string photo, bool allowComments)
            {
                using (var context = new blogEntities())
                {
                        var article = new Article()
                        {
                            Title = title,
                            SubTitle = subTitle,
                            ArticleText = text,
                            Author = author,
                            Photo = photo,
                            CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                            ModifyDate = null,
                            AllowComments = allowComments
                        };

                        foreach (var tg in tags.Split(','))
                        {
                            article.Tags.Add(new Tag() { TagName = tg });
                        }

                        context.Articles.AddObject(article);

                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

Now it throws exception of **duplicate unique key cannot be inserted** How is it done in EF? I'm new to it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a select statement to see if there is already a tag in the database.

```
foreach (var tg in tags.Split(','))
{
    var tag = context.Tags.SingleOrDefault(x => x.TagName == tg);
    if (tag == null)
        tag = new Tag() { TagName = tg };

    article.Tags.Add(tag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your database, you have to add a two-columned primary key to your relationship table.
like this:
[image]

here's my code, the same to yours, and it works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (manytomanyEntities entities = new manytomanyEntities())
            {
                List<B> bList = new List<B>();

                A a = new A
                {
                    Name = "Tim_A"
                };

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    B b = new B
                    {
                        Name = "Tim_B_" + i
                    };

                    entities.B.AddObject(b);
                }

                entities.A.AddObject(a);

                entities.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you, :)